# OnChange not working for dropdown & radioButton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange

I am trying to build the signup form. I have created the `onChange fn` to store the values( credentials) in a state. All the `textfield values` are stored correctly but the `selected dropdown` value and `radiobutton` value is `not` getting reflected when I console the state value.

Here credentials = {
name: texfield,
email: texfield,
password: texfield,
confmpassword: texfield,
`role: radiobutton`,
`forgetQues: dropdown`,
forgetAns: texfield,
}

Below is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SignupPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const goToLogin = () => {
    navigate("/login");
  };

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confmpassword: "",
    role: "",
    forgetQues: "",
    forgetAns: "",
  });

  const onChange = (e, key) => {
    setCredentials((prevCredentials) => ({
      ...prevCredentials,
      [key]: e.target.value,
    }));
    //console.log(credentials);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-3">
        <div id="loginbody">
          <div className="mt-3">
            <h2 className="my-3 display-3">Create your account here </h2>
            <form className="login-form p-5">
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                  Name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  value={credentials.name}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "name")}
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                  Email{" "}
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={credentials.email}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "email")}
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  minLength={5}
                  value={credentials.password}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "password")}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="confmpassword" className="form-label">
                  Confirm Password
                </label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="confmpassword"
                  name="confmpassword"
                  value={credentials.confmpassword}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "confmpassword")}
                  minLength={5}
                  required
                />
              </div>

              {/* ------see here----------------- */}

              <div className="mb-3 col-md">
                <label htmlFor="role" className="form-label">
                  <strong>Role</strong>
                </label>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline mx-4">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role1"
                    value={credentials.role}
                    onSelect={(e) => console.log(e)}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role1">
                    Admin
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role2"
                    value={credentials.role}
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role2">
                    Client
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role3"
                    value={credentials.role}
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role3">
                    Guest
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div className="mb-3 row">
                <div className="form-floating col-6">
                  <select
                    className="form-select"
                    id="forgetQues"
                    name="forgetQues"
                    value={credentials.forgetQues}
                    aria-label="Floating label select example"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "forgetQues")}
                    required
                  >
                    <option>Open this select menu</option>
                    <option value={credentials.forgetQues} >Favourite Sport</option>
                    <option value={credentials.forgetQues} >Favourite Food</option>
                    <option value={credentials.forgetQues} >Favourite City To Visit</option>
                  </select>
                  <label htmlFor="forgetQues">Select Question</label>
                </div>

                {/* -------------upto here---------- */}


                <div className="col-6">
                  <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="forgetAns"
                      name="forgetAns"
                      value={credentials.forgetAns}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e, 'forgetAns')}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="forgetAns">Answer</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-4 col-6 mx-auto">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success ">
                  SignUp
                </button>
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div className="mb-3 text-center">
                <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text center my-3">
                  Already have an account ?
                </div>
                <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-3 col-6 mx-auto">
                  <button onClick={goToLogin} className="btn btn-success ">
                    Login
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;
```

I am solving this error for last one hour but it is not getting resolved. Can I get help?

Comment: you are setting all the `option` values to the same value, so it will just select the first one, these should be hardcoded to uniquely identify them (ie `<option value="sport">Favorite Sport</option>`)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: by setting all the `option.value` properties to `credential.forgetQues` they all get set to an empty string (the initial value) so the onChange updates them, but to the same empty string. Instead give each a hardcoded unique value property.

Comment: Thank you @pilchard; very much appreciated :)